# Is performing IO in constructor good idea?

Tags: java, c#, object-oriented, io, constructor

I have Java (or C#, Python, Kotlin, or other similar language) class that will be used to communicate with client over network. Protocol used by this application allows many different ways to create connection (TCP, unix socket, serial port, …) and perform handshake (plain connection or TLS, with or without authentication). I use separate abstract class that will initialize the connection (called `ConnectionStarter`) and create instance of `Connection`. `Connection` will query the client for some information (this part is **not** dependent on used `ConnectionStarter`) and then allow communication with the other side.

#### Initialisation of the connection

1. `ConnectionStarter` creates the connection
2. `ConnectionStarter` performs handshake
3. `ConnectionStarter` creates `Connection`
4. `Connection` queries the client
5. the connection is initialized and `Connection` can be freely used

The `Connection` will be *always* created by some descendant of `ConnectionStarter`.

---

The question is: Should I include the *step 4* in `Connection` constructor or move it to separate function that *has to* be called?

### Source code

```java
abstract class ConnectionStarter {
    Connection startConnection() {
        Socket socket = inializeSocket(); // Step 1
        performHandshake(socket);         // Step 2
        return new Connection(socket);    // Step 3
    }

    abstract Socket initializeSocket();
    abstract void performHandshake()
}

class Connection {
    Socket socket;

    Connection(Socket socket) {
        this.socket = socket;

        // ━━ The client will be queried now (Step 4) ━━
        queryClient()
    }

    void queryClient() { … } // Step 4
}

// Accessibility modifiers are omitted for simplicity.
```

Comment: Using Java is not a good idea. Use the technology that supports M:N threading model

Comment: @overexchange Code in the question is simplified a lot. I will not create single-threaded application. The real problem is that I do not want to block thread creating the connection.

Comment: Whenever there is combination of CPU + IO bound computation, prefer technology that supports M:N threading model. Java runs on 1:1 threading modle using some C library. Prefer RUST or GO

Comment: "Code in the question is simplified a lot." Code Review is about improving existing, working code. The example code that you have posted is not reviewable in this form because it leaves us guessing at your intentions.  Unlike Stack Overflow, Code Review needs to look at concrete code in a real context. Please see [Why is hypothetical example code off-topic for CR?](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1709)

Comment: @overexchange that sounds interesting do you have some materials regarding the topic that I can read. I've read for threading models on OS level from Operating System Concepts from Abraham, Silberschatz, Galvin and Gagne, but I havent got the chance to see how different languages are using this threading models

Comment: @kuskmen you need to visit each language material and dwell into the details

Comment: Ye, but I cant find anything specific everything is like saying this is very platform specific and framework specific so how can you be so sure its 1:1 for java

Answer (score 1):

Usage of IO in the constructor can be confusing. You can call the `queryClient()` from `ConnectionStarter`:

```java
abstract class ConnectionStarter {
    Connection startConnection() {
        Socket socket = inializeSocket();              // Step 1
        performHandshake(socket);                      // Step 2
        Connection connection = Connection(socket);    // Step 3
        connection.queryClient();
        return connection;
    }

    abstract Socket initializeSocket();
    abstract void performHandshake()
}

class Connection {
    Socket socket;

    Connection(Socket socket) {
        this.socket = socket;
    }

    void queryClient() { … } // Step 4
}

// Accessibility modifiers are omitted for simplicity.
```